# Get TimeDelta between rows, where rows not zero

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a DataFrame

```
import pandas as pd

dates = pd.date_range(start='05.01.2021 00:00:00', end='05.01.2021 00:00:20', freq='S')

values = [1000,343,122.34,342.6,76.45,202,264.32,9454.3,1000,1000,0,0,0,0,0,0,232,2323,5562,3545, 123]

df = pd.DataFrame([dates, values], index=['dates', 'values']).T
```

I want to get the TimeDelta between the rows where `values` is not 0. For every individual range.

So here 9 seconds and 4 seconds. The TimeDelta should appear in a new column at the end of the corresponding timerange.

Any hints on how to do that?

Thx

**EDIT:**

The wanted DataFrame should look like

```
dates = pd.date_range(start='05.01.2021 00:00:00', end='05.01.2021 00:00:20', freq='S')
values = [1000,343,122.34,342.6,76.45,202,264.32,9454.3,1000,1000,0,0,0,0,0,0,232,2323,5562,3545,123]
delta = [None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,'0 days 00:00:09',None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,'0 days 00:00:04']
df = pd.DataFrame([dates, values, delta], index=['dates', 'values', 'timedelta']).T
```

Where the values in column `timedelta` are of dtype `timedelta64[ns]`.

Comment: Could you add the output dataframe you expect in this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dates = pd.date_range(start='05.01.2021 00:00:00', end='05.01.2021 00:00:20', freq='S')
values = [1000,343,122.34,342.6,76.45,202,264.32,9454.3,1000,1000,0,0,0,0,0,0,232,2323,5562,3545, 123]
df = pd.DataFrame([dates, values], index=['dates', 'values']).T

df['timedelta'] = df.groupby(
    (df['values'] == 0).diff().cumsum().fillna(0)
)['dates'].transform(lambda x: x.iloc[-1] - x.iloc[0])
```

Output:

```
    dates   values  timedelta
0   2021-05-01 00:00:00 1000    0 days 00:00:09
1   2021-05-01 00:00:01 343 0 days 00:00:09
2   2021-05-01 00:00:02 122.34  0 days 00:00:09
3   2021-05-01 00:00:03 342.6   0 days 00:00:09
4   2021-05-01 00:00:04 76.45   0 days 00:00:09
5   2021-05-01 00:00:05 202 0 days 00:00:09
6   2021-05-01 00:00:06 264.32  0 days 00:00:09
7   2021-05-01 00:00:07 9454.3  0 days 00:00:09
8   2021-05-01 00:00:08 1000    0 days 00:00:09
9   2021-05-01 00:00:09 1000    0 days 00:00:09
10  2021-05-01 00:00:10 0   0 days 00:00:05
11  2021-05-01 00:00:11 0   0 days 00:00:05
12  2021-05-01 00:00:12 0   0 days 00:00:05
13  2021-05-01 00:00:13 0   0 days 00:00:05
14  2021-05-01 00:00:14 0   0 days 00:00:05
15  2021-05-01 00:00:15 0   0 days 00:00:05
16  2021-05-01 00:00:16 232 0 days 00:00:04
17  2021-05-01 00:00:17 2323    0 days 00:00:04
18  2021-05-01 00:00:18 5562    0 days 00:00:04
19  2021-05-01 00:00:19 3545    0 days 00:00:04
20  2021-05-01 00:00:20 123 0 days 00:00:04
```

Explanation:

The series `(df['values'] == 0).diff().cumsum().fillna(0)` used in the groupby is

```
0     0.0
1     0.0
2     0.0
3     0.0
4     0.0
5     0.0
6     0.0
7     0.0
8     0.0
9     0.0
10    1.0
11    1.0
12    1.0
13    1.0
14    1.0
15    1.0
16    2.0
17    2.0
18    2.0
19    2.0
20    2.0
```

and it identifies groups of consecutive rows where the column `values` is either always 0 or always not 0.

Note that in this way the column `timedelta` contains more than you want. If you want the output to be exactly as you described you can add

```
df.loc[~((df['values'] == 0).diff().shift(-1).fillna(True) & (df['values'] != 0)), 'timedelta'] = np.nan
```

Output:

```
    dates   values  timedelta
0   2021-05-01 00:00:00 1000    NaT
1   2021-05-01 00:00:01 343 NaT
2   2021-05-01 00:00:02 122.34  NaT
3   2021-05-01 00:00:03 342.6   NaT
4   2021-05-01 00:00:04 76.45   NaT
5   2021-05-01 00:00:05 202 NaT
6   2021-05-01 00:00:06 264.32  NaT
7   2021-05-01 00:00:07 9454.3  NaT
8   2021-05-01 00:00:08 1000    NaT
9   2021-05-01 00:00:09 1000    0 days 00:00:09
10  2021-05-01 00:00:10 0   NaT
11  2021-05-01 00:00:11 0   NaT
12  2021-05-01 00:00:12 0   NaT
13  2021-05-01 00:00:13 0   NaT
14  2021-05-01 00:00:14 0   NaT
15  2021-05-01 00:00:15 0   NaT
16  2021-05-01 00:00:16 232 NaT
17  2021-05-01 00:00:17 2323    NaT
18  2021-05-01 00:00:18 5562    NaT
19  2021-05-01 00:00:19 3545    NaT
20  2021-05-01 00:00:20 123 0 days 00:00:04
```